# Should Phantasmal Killer work the same way as Phantasmal Force?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, errata

*Phantasmal* Killer has the same "descriptive" part of its name as the similar spell *Phantasmal* Force.

The key points of Phantasmal Force are (PHB p264):

> You craft an illusion that takes root in the mind of a creature that you can see within range.

and

> The phantasm includes sound, temperature, and other stimuli, also evident only to the creature.

This means that the significantly lower level spell Phantasmal Force is inescapable by being blind or otherwise sensorily impaired compared to the RAW description of Phantasmal Killer. The target experiences the Phantasmal Force illusion even if all their senses are somehow switched off. It is all in their mind and the effected target will rationalise even obvious inconstancies ("My totally destroyed eyes must still be able to see ghosts! Arrrrg!").

Phantasmal Killer does *not* have this in it's description (PHB p265):

> You tap into the nightmares of a creature you can see within range and create an illusory manifestation of its deepest fears, visible only to that creature. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, the target becomes frightened for the duration. At the start of each of the target’s turns before the spell ends, the target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw
>   or take 4d10 psychic damage. On a successful save, the spell ends.

However working in a similar way to Phantasmal Force is perhaps implied by it's name, the single target, the "feel" of it's the description and the way it inflicts psychic damage as time goes on. Historically ([AD&D Illusionist spell](http://pandaria.rpgworlds.info/cant/rules/adnd_spells.htm#Phantasmal%20Killer)) and in other branches of D&D it is clear that this spell works in this manner. In Pathfinder ([Pathfinder wizard/sorcerer spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/phantasmalKiller.html)) Phantasmal Killer is a spell of type *phantasm* which has rules of its own, specifying it all happens inside of the target's head.

The question: **Should Phantasmal Killer work the same way as Phantasmal Force (and perhaps be modified in some canonical source?)**

Is the difference in detail in the spell text a deliberate part of the spell design, or an oversight in bringing the spell forward from previous versions?

---

I can't find any existing errata or sage advice on this.

Running Phantasmal Killer the same way as Phantasmal Force is my group's preference for the spell and the house rule for running it when I am DM

This question is related to a previous question which any answer should consider first: [Does Phantasmal Killer work on a blind target](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90422/does-phantasmal-killer-work-on-a-blind-target)

Comment: Should I take most of the detail in the question out and instead put it in an answer to my own question? It would need to be taken off hold for me to do that.

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to this, if I have it right: *"These two spells are written to behave differently. However they have the same name and 'feel'. I found no errata. Should I take this as a mistake/oversight and ignore that they're written differently and just make them work the same way, or are they deliberately different?"* Is that accurate in capturing what's going on here?

Comment: Yup. Good summary.

Comment: I've added my argument into the question, which was probably a mistake. Thus "Should I take most of the detail in the question out and instead put it in an answer to my own question? "

Comment: There's still a problem with the phrasing.  We don't do opinion-based questions here, and asking a question such as "should x be more like y?" is definitely based in opinion.

Comment: You can still remove your argument/answer from the question while it is closed, especially if you think that will help it reopen. You don't have to wait for there to be somewhere else to put it. (If the question reopens, the removed material will still be archived in this post's edit history — there is no danger of it being lost.)

Answer (score 5):

Phantasmal Killer says (PHB p.263):

> You tap into the nightmares of a creature you can see
>   within range and create an illusory manifestation of its
>   deepest fears, visible only to that creature. The target
>   must make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save,
>   the target becomes frightened for the duration. At the
>   start o f each o f the target’s turns before the spell ends,
>   the target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw
>   or take 4d10 psychic damage. On a successful save,
>   the spell ends.

I assume from your question that you are focusing on the phrase "visible only to that creature" and extending it to mean that if the creature can't see it then it is unaffected by the spell.

I think you are asking that phrase to carry too great a burden. Yes, it is visible only to that creature but no, if the creature is blinded the spell still affects them. Nowhere in the spell description or the description of Blindness (PHB p.290) is there anything to suggest that it would. More generally, **none** of the conditions would stop a *Phantasmal Killer* from Phantasmally Killing you.

Facing your deepest fear is probably going to be worse if you can't see it!

As to the broader question: each spell does what it says it does, no more, no less. Just because spells share elements like names does not mean that they have to be interpreted in light of one another: they each stand alone subject to the general rules of spellcasting.

Further, D&D 5e *rules* stand on their own, it is unwise to look at previous editions to explain the mechanics of this edition. Previous editions made distinctions between phantasms, figments, shadows and other stuff I can't remember - 5e doesn't do this. Phantasmal simply takes on its normal English meaning, that is, it is a synonym for illusionary.

Comment: I have asked the question you are actually answering here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90422/does-phantasmal-killer-work-on-a-blind-target

Comment: Also I have edited the question to show the history of the spell and how it is in the main parallel branch of D&D, Pathfinder, which is one of the reasons why, while I agree with you in general, I have asked the question.

Comment: Finally RAW has a VERY limited scope, and visible means that you can see it ,not that you can imagine it or hear it or anything else. The spell does not specify whether it being visible is a requirement, but it does imply it, which is contrary to the historical spell and inconsistent with the other Phantasm spell.

Comment: +1 for your last paragraph. Trying to interpret *any* game based on understandings of *other games*, no matter how similar, is just asking for trouble.